# Нужна ли запятая после слова "города" и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

"В это трудно поверить, но после одного посещения города, люди стремятся сюда вернуться".

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна, потому что после союза "но"  всего одно предложение(одно подлежащее и одно сказуемое) .И без причастных и деепричастных оборотов.

Answer (score 2):

В это трудно поверить, но после одного посещения города люди стремятся сюда вернуться.
Запятой нет, потому что нет условий обособления членов предложения:стремятся вернуться когда?-после посещения, чего?-города, какого?-одного. Все члены предложения одиночны, оборотов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая запятая не нужна. Предложение сложносочиненное, состоит из 2-х простых. Первая (и единственная) запятая их разделяет.